# create hash equivalent to python call using javascript on browser

Tags: javascript, python, hash

I'm trying to create hash for calling [thesubdb](http://thesubdb.com/api/) api they've given the python implementation of their hash generation method.

My project needs me to create hash on the go on browser and then pass it to my php backend and then call subdbapi using php.
But for that first of all I need to create hash of video file on my browser using javascript.

I'm using the new html 5 file api to read local file on users computer and create hash for same.

```
var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(binary).toString();
console.log(md5);
```

above is my javascript code.
This does not match the output of the python code that they've given which is :

```
 def get_hash(name):
        readsize = 64 * 1024
        with open(name, 'rb') as f:
            size = os.path.getsize(name)
            data = f.read(readsize)
            f.seek(-readsize, os.SEEK_END)
            data += f.read(readsize)
        return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

i'm sure i'm missing something fundamental in my javascript code.

thanks in advance.

Comment: First, the hash is only for the first and last 64K. Be sure that your binary is only this 128k.Second: 2 hash string are not equal as in stringA = stringB, use the python function to compare them, the random var in hash algoritm will output a diferend hash every time

Comment: @cox yes i've checked. binary variable has sum of first and last 64 K only.

Comment: Put a jsfiddle with js